# Custom progress bar with images or Image view with clipdrawable

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have been looking for tutorials on custom progress bars and 95% of what I found was how to customize using colors and gradients NOT with images (basically an image of empty bar with image or full bar on top). When  I try to use images for progress bar, the dimensions are wrong ( wrap content does not work properly and it is half truncated).

I was able to achieve a successful bar with images using image with clipdrawble and level setting.

SOOO, is ProgressBar with images used for its background/progress frowned upon and I should use imageview instead?

Comment: I don't think it is frowned upon. In fact, `ProgressBar` inherently uses a clip drawable to accomplish the animation effect. So, I see no reason why you shouldn't use it. But like you indicated, the only trouble is with how the view measures itself. So you will have to override `onMeasure` to make sure your drawable isn't cut off

Comment: Thank you, any links or example to how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to make sure `ProgressBar` accounts for your custom drawable's dimensions. One way to do it is to override the `onMeasure`. Here is a rough sketch of your custom class's `onMeasure` implementation (compare this against `ProgressBar`'s implementation - you will notice the subtle changes) :

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

    // the super's onMeasure method ignores the dimensions of the custom progress drawable
    // if they are greater than a specified height & width (mMaxHeight  & mMaxWidth). It simply uses those
    // default dimensions for the drawable, consequently resizing them; which is not suitable for larger drawables.
    // So, it is necessary to override this method to allow the ProgressBar to account for the drawable's original
    // dimensions and draw the image/drawable accordingly.
    Drawable d = getProgressDrawable();

    int dw = 0;
    int dh = 0;
    if (d != null) {
        dw = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        dh = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    int[] state = getDrawableState();
    if(mProgressDrawable != null && mProgressDrawable.isStateful())
        mProgressDrawable.setState(state);

    dw += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    dh += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(dw, widthMeasureSpec), resolveSize(dh, heightMeasureSpec));
}
```

You can then set your empty bar as the background for the custom `ProgressBar` like you would usually do for a view - `android:background="@drawable/empty_bar"`

The next part is to set the `progressDrawable`, for which you will have to use a `<layer-list>`, as we want to closely match the progress bar's drawable structure ([default drawable](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml)). Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
       <shape>
         <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
       </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <clip
         android:clipOrientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="bottom"
         android:drawable="@drawable/full_bar">
       </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And finally to animate the progressbar you could use an `ObjectAnimator`:

```
final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator
            .ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 100)
            .setDuration(2000);
animator.start();
```

Comment: THANK you so much. I don't have to use animator right? I can just do "setProgress" Or "setSecondaryProgress"  correct?

Comment: @Snake yes, that's correct! `ObjectAnimator` just does that implicitly through reflection